# Add Class to Result of jQuery $.post

Tags: jquery

I can't get jQuery to add a class to the dom of the result that I get back from a $.post.

Why does this not work?

```
    $.post(url, data, function (result) {
        $(result).addClass('.update');
        $this.closest('.inline').replaceWith(result);
    });
```

The replace is working, but it does not have the .update class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.post(url, data, function (result) {
    var withClass = $(result).addClass('.update');
    $this.closest('.inline').replaceWith(withClass);
});
```

That should work. You're creating a new object, while doing $(result), and then you don't do anything about it. I've changed it in my code.